Are formulas for how many numbers are divisible with a set of n numbers coprime, good? Or I need more proofs?
I am writing a study about prime numbers, but I am an amateur mathematician and my english is not perfect. Any suggestion about notation, proofs and language is welcome.
Suppose we have $N$, a number multiple of $x_1,x_2,\dots x_n$, each one of them being coprime.
Numbers divisible with $x_1$ are $F_1=\frac N{x_1}$
Example: $N=6,\ x_1=2$, then $F_1=3$ numbers are divisible with $2$ from $1$ to $6$.
We can find how many numbers are divisible with $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $2$ methods:
$$
\:F_{2}\:=\frac{N}{x_{1}}+\frac{N}{x_{2}}-\frac{N}{x_{1}x_{2}}\tag{1}
$$
We add numbers divisible with $x_1$ with numbers divisible with $x_2$ and subtracted numbers divisible with both.
Example: $N=6,\ x_1=2,\ x_2=3$, then $F_2=4$ numbers are divisible with $2$ or $3$ from $1$ to $6$.
$$
\:F_{2}\:=\:F_{1}\:+\frac{N}{x_{2}}-\frac{\:F_{1}\:}{x_{2}}\tag{2}
$$
We add numbers divisible with $x_1$ with numbers divisible with $x_2$ and subtract numbers divisible with $x_2$ from those divisible with $x_1$.
The same can be done for more numbers:
$$
\:F_{n+1}\:=\:F_{n}\:+\frac{N}{x_{n+1}}-\frac{\:F_{n}\:}{x_{n+1}}\tag{3}
$$
We add numbers divisible with $x_1$ to $x_n$ with all numbers divisible with $x_{n+1}$ and subtract numbers divisible with $x_{n+1}$ from those divisible with $x_1$ to $x_n$.

It seems like you're trying to compute the number of integers between $1$ and $N$ that are divisible by at least one of $x_1,\dots,x_n$. It will be easier to compute the number of such integers that are divisible by none of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ (and then subtract from $N$), because that will allow you to invoke the Euler phi function $\phi(x_1\times\cdots\times x_n)$.

Assuming $x_1, x_2, \dots x_n$ corresponds to the set of primes $p_1, p_2, \dots p_n$, then I believe your sum can be evaluated as
$$S_n=p_n\#-\phi(p_n\#)\tag{1}$$
where $p_n\#$ is $n^{th}$ primorial
$$p_n\#=\prod_{k=1}^n p_k\tag{2}$$
and $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient function, and in this case your sum corresponds to OEIS entry A053144.

In this case, I believe your sum can also be evaluated as
$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p_n\#} \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \gcd (p_n\#,k)\neq 1 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{3}$$
and also as
$$S_n=\sum\limits_{d>1\land d|p_n\#} (-1)^{\nu(d)+1}\, \frac{p_n\#}{d}\tag{4}$$
where $\nu(d)$ is the number of unique primes dividing $d$ which corresponds to OEIS entry A001221.

But more specific to your question, I believe in this case your formula can be evaluated as
$$S_n=F_{n,n}\tag{5}$$
where $F_{n,k}$ is defined recursively as
$$F_{n,k}=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{p_n\#}{p_1} & k=1 \\
 F_{n,k-1}+\frac{p_n\#}{p_k}-\frac{F_{n,k-1}}{p_k} & k>1 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{6}$$
and $p_k$ is the $k^{th}$ prime.

